# Why is there a street with a date as a name in Belgium?

Tags: belgium

On google maps, in [Bruges Belgium](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.2025467,3.2102135,17z) one can see a street named '18 Oktoberstraat'. What is the significance of this date?

Comment: Belgium was liberated on October 18, 1944.

Comment: That explains it.

Comment: In Mexico there are many streets with dates for names.

Comment: Occurs all over Latin America. Seems a lot happened in the month of May, or *Mayo*, so I kept seeing my name everywhere on street signs :D

Comment: This is a very common practice in Egypt as well, many streets have names of important dates (usually victory dates).

Comment: @CGCampbell: Interesting - you say 1944 (liberation after WWII), Mark Mayo's answer says 1918 (WWI).

Comment: In Brazil it happens all the time. Independence day (07/09) and the day the country changed from a Monarchy to a Republic (15/11) are common names troughout the country.

Comment: Plenty of countries have dates for street names. May 1st, to name but one, is a popular one in many places.

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a page online confirming what's in the comments:

[18 Oktoberstraat](http://brugge-bruges.wikidot.com/18-oktoberstraat)

(translating what Google claims is Dutch, but may well be Flemish, we get:)

> 18th October Street
>
> 18 October Street or XVIII October Street is a reference to the time
>   when the territory from the hands of the Germans fell in 1918.

Comment: Shamelessly converting someone else's comment into an answer... :P

Comment: @JoErNanO well with some actual research and a translation, to be fair ;)